# How to plot some density plot in a group in the way that some of them have the axis label only?

Tags: plotting, alignment

I am trying to have a beautiful set of density plots for a paper. Two questions:
1. How can I justify the panels to be exactly the same in size? Why after bringing them together, the result is so ugly?
2. I have omitted the labels in some panels to have a more symmetric figure. Have you any suggestions for this figure to be better?

```
A1 = DensityPlot[y^2 + \[Xi]^2, {y, 0, 5}, {\[Xi], 0, 0.32}, 
ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", FrameLabel -> {None, \[Xi]}, 
LabelStyle -> Directive[Bold, 17], 
FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, None}, {None, None}}];
A2 = DensityPlot[y^2 + \[Xi]^2, {y, 0, 5}, {\[Xi], 0, 0.32}, 
ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", FrameLabel -> {None, \[Xi]}, 
LabelStyle -> Directive[Bold, 17], 
FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, None}, {None, None}}];
A3 = DensityPlot[y^2 + \[Xi]^2, {y, 0, 5}, {\[Xi], 0, 0.32}, 
ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", FrameLabel -> {None, None}, 
LabelStyle -> Directive[Bold, 17], 
FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, None}, {None, None}}];
A4 = DensityPlot[y^2 + \[Xi]^2, {y, 0, 5}, {\[Xi], 0, 0.32}, 
ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", FrameLabel -> {None, None}, 
LabelStyle -> Directive[Bold, 17], 
FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, None}, {None, None}}];
A5 = DensityPlot[y^2 + \[Xi]^2, {y, 0, 5}, {\[Xi], 0, 0.32}, 
ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", FrameLabel -> {y, \[Xi]}, 
LabelStyle -> Directive[Bold, 17], 
FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, None}, {Automatic, None}}];
A6 = DensityPlot[y^2 + \[Xi]^2, {y, 0, 5}, {\[Xi], 0, 0.32}, 
ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", FrameLabel -> {y, None}, 
LabelStyle -> Directive[Bold, 17], 
FrameTicks -> {{None, None}, {Automatic, None}}];
A7 = DensityPlot[y^2 + \[Xi]^2, {y, 0, 5}, {\[Xi], 0, 0.32}, 
ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", FrameLabel -> {y, None}, 
LabelStyle -> Directive[Bold, 17], 
FrameTicks -> {{None, None}, {Automatic, None}}];

Legended[GraphicsGrid[{{A1}, {A2, A3, A4}, {A5, A6, A7}}], 
Placed[BarLegend[{"TemperatureMap", {0, 1}}, LegendLayout -> "Row"], 
Below]]
```

[image: My final result is as the screenshot.]

Comment: you might like [SciDraw](https://scidraw.nd.edu/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        xc = {{60, .05}, {20, 1}};
      Legended[GraphicsGrid[{{Show[A1, ImagePadding -> xc]}, {Show[A2, 
      ImagePadding -> xc], Show[A3, ImagePadding -> xc], 
     Show[A4, ImagePadding -> xc]}, {Show[A5, ImagePadding -> xc], 
     Show[A6, ImagePadding -> xc], Show[A7, ImagePadding -> xc]}}, 
     ImageSize -> 500, Spacings -> {-75, -60}], 
    Placed[BarLegend[{"TemperatureMap", {0, 1}}, LegendMarkerSize -> 485,
    LegendLayout -> "Row"], Below]]
```

[image: plots]

Comment: but the axis labels are not the same as the single plots :/

Comment: Check the updated plot.

Comment: Which updated plot?!

Comment: How can I set the panels more closely? And also, I want the bar legend to be larger :/

Comment: @ Ak68, Using spacings -> {a, -b}  and LegendMarkerSize -> a, you can change the spacing and marker size. (You can see in updated figures)